# Life expectancy for random walk on half line

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, random-walk

Consider the random walk on $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$:

If $X_t\neq 0$,
$$
X_{t+1} = 
\left\{\begin{matrix}
X_t + 1 & wp.\quad \frac{\gamma}{2}\\
X_t & wp.\quad 1-\gamma\\
X_t - 1& wp.\quad \frac{\gamma}{2}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

Otherwise, we say the random walk dies. Let $T_i$ denote the expected life expectancy if we start at $i$, e.g. $T_0=0$, how can I calculate $T_i,i>0$.

**My Try**

We have

$$\gamma T_i = 1+ \frac{\gamma}{2}T_{i-1}+ \frac{\gamma}{2}T_{i+1}+(1-\gamma)T_i$$

Seems not working.

Comment: Life expectancy of a _symmetric_ random walk? Who says it is finite in the first place?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Do you mean $T_i$ might be $+\infty$?

Comment: Yeah, I think so (unless someone more knowledgeable proves otherwise, that is).

Comment: Yep, almost surely finite but with infinite expectation. Oh, and the recursion should read $$T_i = 1+ \frac{\gamma}{2}T_{i-1}+ \frac{\gamma}{2}T_{i+1}+(1-\gamma)T_i$$